# Quotes, inside quotes, inside quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, quotes, double-quotes

I try to put `\` before quotes, change double for single quotes... but nothing. Everyone have a solution or tip? Thanks!

This is the code:

```
html.append('<li lat="'+dataRaw[key].optionsDir['gpsLatitude']+'" lon="test">'+thumbnailHtml+descriptionHtml+'</li>');
```

Error occurs in this part of code:

```
['gpsLatitude']
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks correct.

Comment: The question is really unclear (even with the edit). Unless there are `"` in the value that `dataRaw[key].optionsDir['gpsLatitude']` returns (which seems unlikely), that should be fine.

Comment: "Error occurs in this part of code:" - What is the error you are speaking of?

Comment: I might try using double quotes for the `optionsDir["gpsLatitude"]`. I wonder if the string concatenation is superseding the lookup and bombing the line? (I'd be _surprised_, but hey.)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason the code you posted would break is if the *value of*...

```
dataRaw[key].optionsDir['gpsLatitude']
```

... contains quotes, so you can escape them!

```
var lat = dataRaw[key].optionsDir['gpsLatitude']
          .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')  // replace "
          .replace(/'/g, '&#39;');  // replace '
html.append('<li lat="' + lat + '" lon="test">' + 
      thumbnailHtml + descriptionHtml + 
      '</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for yout tip, dont work for me, but help me so much!! Thanks =). I try all sugestions of us friends in comments,  I solve the problem with adjusts in php and ajax. Other method, dont work.